# Firefox is opening but terminating immediately when we launch using Selenium WebDriver

Tags: java, selenium, firefox

When I open Firefox manually, it is opening correctly and functioning as expected but when I try to launch the same Firefox using Selenium WebDriver, code:

```
WebDriver driver = new FirefoxDriver();
```

Firefox is launching and after few moments am getting error "Firefox has stopped working" with the 2 options:

1. Check online for a solution and close the program
2. Close the program

Please try to resolve this issue as my many of the applications runs on Firefox.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/114726/discussion-on-question-by-amith-firefox-is-opening-but-terminating-immediately-w).

Answer (score 1):

Update to FF 47.0.1, they fixed the bug that was causing the crash.  See https://www.mozilla.org/firefox/47.0/releasenotes/

Comment: Good call. For some reason, I've been getting unsecure connection warnings when going to mozilla.org lately, so if you need to get this update another way, you can go to the options dropdown, click on '?', and then click About Firefox.

Answer (score 0):

Downgrade your firefox version to FF 46.0 as the FF 47.0 has no support for webdriver. once you downgrade the Firefox go and disable the auto upgrade option by following the below mentioned steps:

1. Open firefox: Press F10 > Tools > options
2. Go to the Advanced tab.
3. Navigate to the Update tab.
4. Uncheck the option 'Use a background service to install update'
5. Uncheck 'Automatically install updates (recommended: improved security)' by clicking the other button in list 'Never check for updates (not recommended: security risk)' and click ok

Comment: @Pankaaj: Am unable to Uncheck 'Automatically install updates (recommended: improved security)'

Comment: It's a radio button list so you wont be able to uncheck it until you check any other button in the list item . So click the radio button in front of 'Never check for updates (not recommended: security risk)' so that the previous one will be unchecked. -My mistake I should have added it in the answer only. so doing it now.

Comment: Yes your correct that is the radio button it will get uncheck when we click on other radio button, but i am not able to click on other radio button as well.

Answer (score 0):

- If you are using WebDriverManager then check the version of the bonigarcia dependency at
  https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/io.github.bonigarcia/webdrivermanager
  *After that, open your pom.xml file and update your WebDriverManager version for bonigarcia.
  Thanks

[Picture from pom.xml for WebDriverManager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wsRSH.png)